# Company-dabbrev does not work on eglot

Tags: company-mode, lsp, eglot

I use emacs 28/29 on windows.
this is my config.

```
(use-package company
  :ensure t
  :pin gnu
  :init (global-company-mode)
  :config
  (setq company-backends '(company-dabbrev)
    company-idle-delay 0
    company-echo-delay 0))
```

```
(use-package eglot
  :ensure t
  :commands (eglot eglot-ensure eglot-server-programs)
  :hook ((c-mode . eglot-ensure)
         (c++-mode . eglot-ensure))
  :config
  (add-hook 'eglot-mode-hook (lambda () (setq-local
                     company-backends '(company-dabbrev
                                ;; company-capf
                                ))))
  (add-to-list 'eglot-server-programs '((c++-mode c-mode) "D:/LLVM/bin/clangd.exe"))
  (add-hook 'eglot--managed-mode-hook (lambda () (flymake-mode -1))))
```

Comment: What's the question? Please be specific. Thx.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. If I have enable EGLOT(c, c++-mode), no dabbrev in company completion list. text-mode or emacs-lisp-mode it's work.

Comment: Let me briefly explain why. `company` polls each backends until one of them can provide complements. But the lsp with the capf backend is not sure if it can provide complements (it needs to wait for the lsp-server to respond), so it tells the company I have candidates by default. This results in later backends not being used, even if the lsp does not return a complement in the end.

Comment: The above is my recollection and I can't find the discussion in company-mode issues for now. Solutions include merging multiple backends using `:with` or considering super-capf from package cape.

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work in text-mode and emacs-lisp-mode either, I think you need to provide the values for company-backends in the question, local and global.

Comment: Please: put all relevant info for your question in the *question* itself, not in comments. Similarly, @TianshuWang: post answers as answers, not as comments. Comments can be deleted at any time, and they're not searchable.

Comment: @Drew Thanks for the advice, I didn't understand clearly in which mode he was having problems yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

The `company-mode` polls each backend until one of them can provide completions. However, the lsp/eglot with the capf backend is not sure if it can provide completions (it needs to wait for the lsp-server to respond), so it tells the company I have candidates by default. This results in later backends not being used, even if the lsp-server does not return any completion in the end.

Solutions include merging multiple backends by `:with` or considering `super-capf` from package `cape`.

**Attention**: The above answer is my recollection and I can't find the source for now, maybe at the discussion or issue of `company-mode`.